# Audio skipping in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm building a website for a musician and they have provided a series of audio files to be included on their website.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/react-player/reaplay) component for an audio player, but I'm finding that the audio skips. The skipping happens only on Chrome, only on macOS, only when another program is using the microphone. However, the client uses Chrome on a Mac and was on a call with me when they first saw the site (yikes). The component uses the HTML5 HTMLAudioElement.

I've been trying to modify the code from the component to get it to work, and I've figured out that it skips every time the state variable storing the current time of the audio updates for the UI.

```
var startTimer = function startTimer() {
clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
intervalRef.current = setInterval(function () {
  if (audioRef.current.ended) {
    if (!isStopPlayMoreSong) {
      if (isShuffleList) {
        playRandom();
      } else {
        if (isRepeat) {
          onScrub(0);
          audioRef.current.play();
        } else {
          toNextTrack();
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    setTrackProgress(audioRef.current.currentTime);
  }
}, 100); <- update interval
};
```

This code runs to set the track progress every interval, which is the same interval on which the track skips.

My code looks like this (though it doesn't affect the skipping)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Reaplay } from "reaplay";

const NewAudioPlayer = ({ trackName, songs, trackInfo }) => {
  return (
    <Reaplay tracks={songs} startIndex={0} isPlaying={false}>
      {(player) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="audio-player">
              <div style={{ alignItems: "center", width: "100%" }}>
                <div>
                  <div
                    className={`circular-play-pause-button ${
                      player.isPlaying ? "playing" : ""
                    }`}
                    onClick={() => {
                      player.setIsPlaying(player.isPlaying ? false : true);
                    }}
                  >
                    {player.isPlaying ? (
                      //play/pause button
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <input
                    type="range"
                    value={player.trackProgress}
                    step=".1"
                    min="0"
                    max={
                      player.duration ? player.duration : `${player.duration}`
                    }
                    className="progress"
                    onChange={(e) => player.onScrub(e.target.value)}
                    onMouseUp={(e) => player.onScrubEnd(e)}
                    onKeyUp={(e) => player.onScrubEnd(e)}
                  />
                  <p>
                    {player.trackProgressText.substring(1)}/
                    {player.durationText.substring(1)}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Reaplay>
  );
};

export default NewAudioPlayer;
```

Comment: It's possible that what is happening is that each time that timer runs, the subsequent rerender requires enough CPU time on this person's machine as to disrupt the audio. If his machine is under high load (would be interesting to check his current CPU usage), then it's possible the re-render is stealing what limited CPU time they have left.

Comment: I would say it's likely that the usage of the microphone is a complete red herring, and it's more likely that that just happens to be when they are using a resource-intensive application, such as Zoom or other video conferencing software. That would exacerbate any performance problems he is having.

Comment: That said it's very strange as the rerender should be really cheap. Does he have any chrome extensions installed? Ask him to see if it happens in incognito mode (which has no extensions by default). A rogue extension is exactly the kind of thing that could be causing this.

Comment: (Have him close the non-icognito window whilst he tries this.)

Comment: @adsy I was also curious about CPU usage, so I opened a Mac, launched Voice Memos, started a recording, (which peaked at 1.2% CPU load) and played audio on this webpage and experienced the same issue. I tried again in Safari and Firefox and had no issue

Comment: Hmm ok. Well that does make me consider that there's something deeper going on here. The above rules out a lot of the more likely possibilities so it could well be some obscure interaction being chrome and osx's audio drivers. If it *was* system level like that then it'd be simply beyond your control. Especially if confirmed across multiple macs. From a practical point of view, you could create a minimal example of the problem and demonstrate this to them that its beyond your control and stress the lack of value in solving such a specific issue normal users probably wont encounter.

Comment: If you are able to reliably repro this on multiple macs as well, I would file a Chromium bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list. Youve identified its related to the timeout (which causes DOM operations), but that doesn't mean this isn't a chrome bug. Those DOM operations are incredibly cheap and it shouldn't cause issues with audio playback. The involvement of microphone is so odd it leads one to thing about browser bugs. I must say I don't take coming to this conclusion lightly, as its a very rare circumstance. But there's not many other conclusions to come to.